# how to let the server forward received message from any client to all connected clients in java

Tags: multithreading, client-server

I'm trying to make a chat system project (still incomplete) using java, but I need small help in forwarding the client's received message.

The server is working as multi-threading so many clients can connect to it, what I want is: (Assumed scenario) if 6 clients are connected to the server, then one of them send a message, it should be forwarded to all connected clients through the server.

here is the 2 codes..

Server side

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
public class ChatServer implements Runnable
{
    Socket csocket;
    ChatServer(Socket csocket){ this.csocket = csocket; }

public static void main(String[]args)throws Exception
{
    ServerSocket sersock=new ServerSocket(3000);
    System.out.println("Server  ready for chatting");
    while(true)
    {
        Socket sock =sersock.accept();
        new Thread(new ChatServer(sock)).start();}
}
public void run()
{
    try{
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": HELLO");
            BufferedReader keyRead=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            OutputStream ostream=csocket.getOutputStream();
            PrintWriter pwrite=new PrintWriter(ostream, true);
            InputStream istream=csocket.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader receiveRead=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(istream));
            String receiveMessage, sendMessage;

            while(true) {
                    if((receiveMessage=receiveRead.readLine())!=null)
                        {
                            System.out.print(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": ");
                            if(receiveMessage.equals("QUIT"))
                                Thread.currentThread().stop();
                                else
                                    System.out.println(receiveMessage);}
                        sendMessage=keyRead.readLine(); 
                        pwrite.println(sendMessage); 
                        System.out.flush();}
        } catch (IOException e){ System.out.println(e); }

}

}
```

client side

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
public class ChatClient
{
public static void main(String[]args)throws Exception
{
Socket sock =new Socket("localhost", 3000);
// reading from keyboard (keyRead object)
BufferedReader keyRead=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
// sending to client (pwrite object)
OutputStream ostream=sock.getOutputStream();
PrintWriter pwrite=new PrintWriter(ostream, true);

// receiving from server ( receiveRead  object)
InputStream istream=sock.getInputStream();
BufferedReader receiveRead=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(istream));

System.out.println("Start the chitchat, type and press Enter key");

String receiveMessage, sendMessage;
while(true)
{
sendMessage=keyRead.readLine();// keyboard reading
pwrite.println(sendMessage);// sending to server
System.out.flush();// flush the data
    if((receiveMessage=receiveRead.readLine())!=null)//receive from server
{
System.out.println(receiveMessage);// displaying at DOS prompt
}
}
}
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When client connect to server, store client socket in a Map at server end. When any client sends message, iterate through all sockets on Map and send message.

Comment: Useful link: http://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/javanetexamples/#chat

Answer (score 0):

I write these types of server applications frequently, as a way of connection client through a relay server when direct connections between them are not possible. The solution is simple, put each `socket` that you receive from the `accept()` function into a List or Tree of your choice.

```
List<Socket> connectionList = new ArrayList<Socket>();
...
Socket sock =sersock.accept();
connectionList.add(sock);
...
for (Socket connection : connectionList) {
      connection.getOutputStream().write(msgBytes);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer guys :) , Mr Andy can you tell me in which part of the code I should use these commands? because I'm not really familiar with lists

Comment: You should put it in the thread at the server, after receiving a new message. Use the above code, for loop, to send the response to all connected client. Please upvote if you like the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mr Andy I tried what you said but I'm getting this message "cannot find symbol method write(java.lang.String)", any ideas?